# How to use linked list ADT in a function?

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, copy, queue

I am trying to copy a queue from another queue but the function gives the following compile errors:

'class Node' has no member named 'isEmpty'

'class Node' has no member named 'enqueue'

'class Node' has no member named 'getFirst'

'class Node' has no member named 'dequeue'

'cannot convert 'operations*' to 'Node*' in return

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Queue.h"
using namespace std;

Node* copyQueue(Node* q1)
{
    operations *q2 = new operations();

    while(q1->isEmpty()!= True)
    {
        q2 -> enqueue( q1 -> getFirst() );
        q1 -> dequeue();
    }
    return q2;
}

int main()
{
    operations *q1 = new operations();

    int temp, n;
    cout << "Enter queue size: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter data to copy: ";
    for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
    {
        cin >> temp;
        q1 -> enqueue(temp);
    }
    copyQueue(q1);
    cout << "Copied Queue = ";
    q2 -> display();
}
```

**queue.h source code:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;

class operations
{
public:

    Node *front= NULL;
    Node *newdata= NULL;
    Node *rear= NULL;

    void enqueue(int item)
    {
        newdata = new Node(item);

        if(front==NULL && rear == NULL)
        {
            front = rear = newdata;
        }
        else
        {
            rear->next = newdata;
            rear = newdata;
        }
    }

    void dequeue()
    {
        Node *temp = front;
        front = front->next;
        delete temp;
    }

    bool isEmpty()
    {
        if(front == NULL)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    int getFirst()
    {
        return front -> item;
    }

    void display()
    {
        Node *temp= front;
        while(temp!= NULL)
        {
            cout<<temp->item<<"->";
            temp= temp->next;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Need to see how `Node` is defined as well. Put together a [mcve].

Comment: At a guess, you have the parameter type for `copyQueue` wrong. You pass it a `operations *`, and the missing members from `Node` are in `operations`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of your first function is not correct. It is supposed to take a queue and return a queue, but you have specified `Node` for both.

So change:

```
Node* copyQueue(Node* q1)
```

to:

```
operations* copyQueue(operations* q1)
```

Some other things to correct:

- In `main` you have not declared `q2`. Also, it does not capture the return value from the `copyQueue` call, so change:

  ```
  copyQueue(q1);
  ```

  to:

  ```
  operations *q2 = copyQueue(q1);
  ```
- `True` should be `true`.
- `dequeue` should set `rear` to `NULL` whenever the queue becomes empty. So change:

  ```
  front = front->next;
  delete temp;
  ```

  to:

  ```
  front = front->next;
  if(front==NULL) 
  {
      rear = NULL;
  }
  delete temp;
  ```
- As `isEmpty()` returns a boolean value, you should not have to write:

  ```
  while(q1->isEmpty()!= true)
  ```

  ...but just:

  ```
  while(!q1->isEmpty())
  ```
- For the same reason the `isEmpty` method should not need an `if...else`. Change:

  ```
  if(front == NULL)
      return true;
  else
      return false;
  ```

  to:

  ```
  return front == NULL;
  ```
- When `front` is `NULL` then necessarily the same is true for `rear`, so there is no need for this double check:

  ```
  if(front==NULL && rear == NULL)
  ```

  It can be just:

  ```
  if(front==NULL)
  ```